# How to modify deeper level attributes in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
{articleId:"1"
 promotions:[{promoterId:"2"
              viewerIps:['3', '4', '5']},
              {promoterId:"6"
              viewerIps:['7', '8', '9']}]}
```

Basically, I want to keep track of how many people (and their IP's) view some article based on a user specific link they share.

If someone is the first view a specific article from that promoter, I can push to the promotions array like this:

```
Views.update({articleId:articleId}, {$push: {promotions:{promoterId:promoterId,
viewerIps:[viewerIp]}}});
```

But suppose the I want to push onto a specific viewerIps array -- specific to both the articleId and the promoterId. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.` notation

```
Views.update({articleId:articleId}, 
   {
      $push: {"promotions.0.viewerIps"  :viewerIp}
   },
      $set:  {"promotions.0.promoterId":promoterId}
});
```

The number there `0` comes from the index position in the array you want to alter. You can use the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/), `$` to make a query on which array you want to alter. The reason i've used a number above instead of `$` is that the `$` isn't fully supported on meteor yet.

You can use it only on the server if you want to. [There is an open github ticket about this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/153)

Comment: So I think what I want to do is this: `Views.update({articleId:articleId, promotions:{promoterId:promoterId}}, {$push: {promotions.$.viewerIps: viewerIp}});` But you're telling me that the $ isnt implemented? So in the mean time I'll have to fetch all Views, find the index, and then use that for an insert? That sounds miserable...

Comment: Yeah, it depends though. It works fine server side without any hiccups. The work around is to fetch the index as you describe or to use a method call to transfer the workload to the server

Comment: I'm doing it on the server so that works. A little correction on my part: `Views.update({articleId:articleId, "promotions.promoterId":promoterId}, {$push: {"promotions.$.viewerIps": viewerIp}});` Totally worked though! :)

Answer (score 0):

One aspect of meteor I love is that you get to use javascript/coffeescript **everywhere**.  I humbly suggest you extend that strategy to your use of mongo updates.  I find myself just using my json/object manipulation abilities directly and $set the whole thing, rather than learning another syntax.  Some would say it is premature optimization to limit the fields you retrieve until proven it would have an effect, so you probably retrieve the data anyway.

In the abstract, there may be some time when it is just horrible to move huge data structures around, but if you get to that point with this problem, creating a new document for each promoter may be what you should do anyway.  Especially as my instinct says I would probably like more info than promoter id and viewer ip.